# Convert KML hex color to 32 bit ARGB

Tags: c#

How to convert a hex color into 32 bit ARGB using C#.  (without using the built-in color functions)

I tried this but it is not producing the correct color:

```
string colorcode = "#ff465a82";
int argb = Int32.Parse(colorcode.Replace("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Thanks Before Hand

**Update #1:**

Found this but does not work: (Also I am sure it can be done in one line of code)

```
string colorcode = "ff465a82";

string a = colorcode.Substring(0, 2);
string r = colorcode.Substring(2, 2);
string g = colorcode.Substring(4, 2);
string b = colorcode.Substring(6, 2);

// To integer
int iCol = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
```

**Solution**

Michael Liu, you got this one!  Here is the final solution, notice google earth uses ABGR and the standard is ARGB!

```
// Note Google KML Colors are not in standard format of ARGB
// Google KML Colors are stored as ABGR
public int kmlToARGB(string kmlhexcolor)
{

    kmlhexcolor = kmlhexcolor.TrimStart('#');

    string A = kmlhexcolor.Substring(0, 2);
    string B = kmlhexcolor.Substring(2, 2);
    string G = kmlhexcolor.Substring(4, 2);
    string R = kmlhexcolor.Substring(6, 2);
    int decValue = int.Parse(A + R + G + B, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    return decValue;

}
```

Comment: `Replace('#', '0x')` so it at least LOOKS like a hex string? `ff465a82` is just some random letters/numbers, `0xff465a82` is a hex string.

Comment: @Marc B: 1) Those should be double quotes, this is not PHP or JS 2) `NumberStyles.HexNumber` explicitly requires that the input string *not* be prefixed with `0x` for it to work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx

Comment: @user3062349: Could you explain what you mean by "does not work"? Are you getting an error, or just a wrong color?

Comment: First example, wrong color.  In the second one (update #1) syntax error.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe the color you expect and the color you're actually getting? (For example, are you expecting a bluish color, but you're getting tan?) Also, is the alpha correct or incorrect?

Comment: When I use the first example's results and assign them to a color object, the colors are mixed up.  A=255, R=70, G=90, G=130.  I think you are getting close...  The hex color data comes from a KML file. (Google Earth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that the drawing API you're using expects color values to be in the format `AARRGGBB` but your original color code is in the format `#AABBGGRR` (or vice versa).

Try swapping red and blue before parsing the value:

```
string colorcode = "#ff465a82";
int argb = Int32.Parse(
    colorcode.Substring(1, 2) + // Alpha
    colorcode.Substring(7, 2) + // Red
    colorcode.Substring(5, 2) + // Green
    colorcode.Substring(3, 2),  // Blue
    NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an unsigned int (`UInt32`), both for the type of `argb` and for the `Parse` method.

Your number has the top bit set (because the top byte is 0xff), which is going to be parsed as a negative number if you put it into a 32-bit signed int.

Comment: Tried, unsigned and then returned an int and still not getting correct color:  (i need to return an int, is that the problem?)  


UInt32 argb = UInt32.Parse(colorcode.Replace("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);


return (int)argb;

Comment: I need to return an int...  How can I do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, the second code *of course* gives syntax errors: You are trying to bit-shift strings. How do you think that’s supposed to work?

Second, you cannot do this as a signed 32bit integer. The largest number you can represent with signed 32bit integers is `2147483648`. `0xFFFFFFFF` is `4294967295` though. For unsigned 32bit integers, the largest number is `4294967295` too. That’s not by chance. If you look at the ARGB hex string (`0x12345678`), you can see that there are four blocks of 8 bit numbers, each encoding a single color channel. So: **ARGB colors are unsigned 32 bit integers**.

As such, *any* try to get an `int` from that color will fail.

Instead, you will have to keep the `uint` type around wherever you need to pass ARGB colors.

```
string colorcode = "ff465a82";
uint argb = uint.Parse(colorcode, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

Console.WriteLine(argb);                            // 4282800770
Console.WriteLine("Alpha: {0}", argb >> 24);        // Alpha: 255
Console.WriteLine("Red: {0}", (argb >> 16) & 0xFF); // Red: 70
Console.WriteLine("Blue: {0}", (argb >> 8) & 0xFF); // Blue: 90
Console.WriteLine("Green: {0}", argb & 0xFF);       // Green: 130
```

Comment: Well, it depends on the API. For example, [`System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts an `int`.